# Evaluate $\int_\gamma \frac{1+z}{1-\cos z} dz$ where $\gamma$ is origin centered circle with radius 7

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am beginner at this topic, i need help to solve the following question for my exam preparation.

Evaluate $$\int_\gamma \frac{1+z}{1-\cos z} dz$$ where $\gamma$ is origin centered circle with radius 7.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)?

Comment: Where are the poles of your function located at? Which ones are located within your contour? Can you calculate the residue at each?

Answer (score 0):

If you have learned the Residue Theorem, you should be able to apply it; calculate the residues at each pole inside the contour.

If not, you can 1) plug in a suitable parameterization of the path, and use brute force to compute the resulting integral (with a real variable), or 2) obtain the indefinite integral away from the pole, it should contain branch cut(s), and your integral can be obtained by monodromy.